# html input value turns to placeholder

Tags: python, html, django

I' m working with Django project with Python. I have a example input area like this;

```
<form method="GET">
 <input type="text" name="product_code" placeholder="Please enter product code">
 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Search</button>
</form>
```

When I send the form with "Search" button, I want to see inputted value but I see placeholder again "Please enter product code".

I changed the placeholder with {{variable}} but it doesn't work.

Comment: Can you show us the code in your view?

Comment: You should use `value="{{ variable }}"` where `variable` is something you pass through the context of the template with the value you search for.

Comment: in my view I have p_code variable, 
p_code = request.GET.get('product_code')

Answer (score 0):

Use This Code

```
<form method="GET">
    <input type="text" id="text" name="product_code" placeholder="Please enter product code">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" id="btn">Search</button>
</form>
<script>
    var a = location.search && location.search.substr(1).replace(/\+/gi, " ").split("&");
    for (var i in a) {
        var s = a[i].split("=");
        a[i] = a[unescape(s[0])] = unescape(s[1]);
    }
    for (i in a) {
        document.getElementById("text").value=a[i]
    };
</script>
```

Just give id="text" to your input